# Mapr Phoenix integration

Tags: hbase, mapr, apache-phoenix

I'm gonna migrate data from RDBMS to HDFS hadoop file system. Data from RDBMS will be converted as a file and it will be uploaded to hadoop. I'm using MapR M7. 
Is it possible to integrate MapR M7 with Phoenix?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which DB implementation you are using with M7. MapR M7 supports two different Apache HBase "compatible" implementations MapR-DB and HBase, both of which will sit on top of MapR-FS. The HBase distribution in M7 does support Phoenix, however, at least as on date and based on the official documentation, MapR-DB does not support Phoenix (Drill is what is suggested, I believe.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Phoenix and other SQL-on-Hadoop technologies with MapR. As a MapR customer, you are entitled to enterprise support 24x7. If you reach out to MapR support you should receive a quick response.

Comment: M7 tables do not support Phoenix and probably never will due to lack of Co-Processor support. https://community.mapr.com/thread/8937

Answer (score 0):

MapR doesn't provide support for Phoenix.